# Can you set the download path for the Apparition driver?

Tags: google-chrome, capybara, apparition

I'm dabbing into switching over our acceptance tests to the Capybara/[Apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) driver. I want to add specific Chrome browser preferences for the download path.

I can't find any documentation on this, and by the look of things I can't use a Chrome options object like I would with Capybara, Selenium and chromedriver, such as:

```
@options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

def specific_chrome_options
  preferences = {
      prompt_for_download: false,
      default_directory: FilesDownloadHelper::PATH # custom profile needed to test file downloads
  }
 
@options.add_preference(:download, preferences)
```

I've tried to set this with a '--user-data-dir' args and preferences file created during run, but it doesn't seem like it is picking it up.

Perhaps the driver is still in a beta state for these kind of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `apparition` downloads should go to whatever directory `Capybara.save_path` is set to.